# How to list all event observer conflicts in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

In Magento, we can use the command from **magerun** to show all rewrite module conflicts:

```
magerun dev:module:rewrite:conflicts
```

Do you have any ideas how to show all **events** are being listened at the same time?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend free extension [FireGento_Debug](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-debug):

It lets you check rewrites, some system information and also all registered observer.

[image]